# How do I build an array using numpy.repeat where each element is 1% over the previous one?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an initial value of salary=500. I want it to increment by 1% every year so my array would look like `[500,550,605,665.5]` etc. Essentially multiplying `1.1` to each previous value.

I was using a loop for this, but was curious if it could be done using `numpy.arange` and `numpy.repeat` somehow?

```
salary=500
for i in range(0,15,1):
    salary=1.1*salary
    print(salary)
```

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Use `1.1` as the base to create an *exponential-array* and scale it with the starting value -

```
In [52]: 500*(1.1**np.arange(4)) # 4 is number of output elements
Out[52]: array([500. , 550. , 605. , 665.5])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cumprod` to calculate the increase over time:

```
inc = np.full(15,1.1).cumprod()
```

This multiplies each element in an array of 1.1 by the previous value and accumulates. Then calculate your `salary`:

```
salary = 500*inc
```

Answer (score 0):

One percent is 0.01 ((1/100)*1) not 0.1

```
# 1% is 0.01 not 0.1(10%) 
salary=500
years=input("How many years shall pass?")
print(salary)
for i in range (1,int(years)):
     salary=(salary/100)*101
     print(int(salary))
```

Is this what you mean?
You can also make a list (.append) for the array though for this type of programs I would use fortran. Though I don't know what your objective with this is.